# When I try and store a variable it does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var cl = 0;
var menu = function(){

    if(cl === 0){
        $('.menu_nav').animate({left: '0px'}, 200);

        $('body').animate({left: '285px'}, 200);

        var cl = cl + 1;
        console.log("First " + cl);
    }else{
        $('.menu_nav').animate({left: '-285px'}, 200);

        $('body').animate({left: '0px'}, 200);

        var cl = cl - 1;
        console.log("Second " + cl);
    };
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu-btn').on('click', function(){
        $(menu);
    });
});
```

I am trying to make a menu button open a side panel when clicked, but when clicked again should close it. I have tried += and =+ neither work. I am clueless on what I should do. It prints out "first 1" every time I click it, it never goes to else like it should.

//The problem was solved I was declaring a variable inside the function so it would be 0 every time. Now I put the cl outside of the function and it works great because it now can store a variable and change instead of being set to 0 every time the variable was called.

Comment: Why don't you just call the function?

Comment: @AndrewL. because it has to happen every time i click on the menu button not as soon as the document is ready.

Comment: You set a variable to `0` then check if it's `0` right on the next line, how could it not be `0`?

Comment: I'm saying, why don't you just call the function inside the event handler instead of wrapping it as a jQuery object

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek obviously its 0 at first then in the if it should add a 1 to it then go to else and minus a 1 and repeat.

Comment: You should read up on how variables work in JavaScript. Every time your function is called you created a local variable and **set** it to `0`, then right away check if it's `0`. It's impossible for that condition to be `false`. Also `var` is for defining a variable, not for changing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the function menu is executed the value of cl is reset-ed to 0. Try using a global variable, like declare `var cl = 0;` before `var menu = function(){` And inside your function change all `var cl` to `cl`. You can check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/uyv46v9q/) also for the logic.